# Ubuntu 16.04 Login Issue after installing Nvidia Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login

Got a new PC with a GTX 1080 TI and an i7-8700K Intel core. 
I installed ubuntu and after specifying nomodeset everything worked. So far so good. Next, I wanted to install the driver for my graphics card but no matter what I do, when I reboot I get stuck at the login screen.

- I tried deleting .Xauthority but it doesn't change anything.
- .xsession-erros tells me

  openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
  cannot connect to brltty at :0
  gnome-session (Unity) main process (2235) terminated with status 1
- Also tried different ubuntu version (16.04 and 17) as well as different drivers (the proprietary and the open source ones)
- Tried disabling nouveau
- Setting permissions on /tmp
- Updating all packages
- Using gdm instead of lightdm

Maybe the problem is that I have the onboard graphics card and the NVIDIA card?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I have two HDMI outputs (one from the motherboard and one from the graphics card). I was using the one from the motherboard and after switching to the one from the graphics card everything worked perfectly.